# How to solve problem with co-worker without repercussions

Tags: communication, colleagues

I am a Web developer and I am working with a relatively new company, I am hired part time because I'm a student. A few weeks ago the company hired another developer for full time that wants to do some changes and the bosses are green light about it. So here comes my problem. I asked him face to face what should I learn to be useful and he told me "X" would be good since it helps the project to be delivered faster and of course I started to get a hang on it and the bosses asked me how I was doing and what am I studying and I told them that I studied "X", because I talked with my co-worker and we agreed upon this. At that moment they asked him about this and he denied this and said that he never told me as such. How can I solve this issue without quitting or looking like I am at fault.

Comment: Hi, wickerman, I've read your post, but I'm having difficulty seeing where the problem is exactly. did the bosses say that studying "X" was wrong? Is "X" not actually useful for this project? Had the bosses given you other work that you should have been doing when you had been studying?

Comment: The bosses were asking me why did I study that because we won't use it in the near future. Before I started learning "X" I asked my bosses if it is ok to make it 50/50 learning/working and it was ok. @teacherkshuang

Comment: I see now, thanks. Meanwhile, I've upvoted both Kilisi and Pete's answers, but I would also add that in the future, I would have asked my bosses on what would be useful to learn to help with the project and not the other developer. Otherwise, you find yourself in a situation such as this one. Then, if you still want to ask the other developer, you may, but just remember who you're working for :).

Comment: I asked them weeks before it the company changes direction and they told me that I should ask my colleague because he has more experience and would give me a better direction on what I should focus on. Ever since, I don't trust anybody and ask them if they are sure and in front of someone else too.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the problem even more in-depth. In which case, I definitely stand by my upvotes for the answers by Pete and Kilisi -- always leave a paper trail.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the answer and comments. It was my fault for not knowing what and how and I will try to avoid such events!

Comment: We've all been there :) :/. Live and learn :). At least we're taking steps to resolve it, especially you!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I asked the bosses what should I focus on, got sent to this co-worker, he told me what to do, nobody was happy. I didn't do it because I wanted to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just shrug it off and keep doing the best you can. It doesn't really matter unless it's impacting on your reports.

Next time ask via email so you have a paper trail. It's important to keep trails on everything, something as simple as:

"Hello [insert name], just clarifying what I should focus on, it was XXX wasn't it?

Regards
Me"

Comment: Emails like this can look a bit odd when you're sitting in the same room.  It's basically saying "I'm putting this in writing now because you might lie about it later on".

Comment: Yep, I emailed my managers back in the day when they sat right next to me :) I don't care what it makes me look like, it's not a beauty pageant. Lost count of the times when a paper trail was useful especially when I'm the only one with it :)

Comment: @Pete I usually just say I have a bad memory and ask them to send me an email in any case just so that I have a reminder. That way it doesn't seem odd at all. I have had people email me in the same room too. My boss and I do that all the time because we both forget things :)

Comment: I agree.  However, in this situation (after a known misunderstanding/deception), asking for an email trail could come across as (and I really, really hate using this term) passive aggressive. Absolutely nothing wrong with a project-related paper-trail though.

Comment: It slowed my project by 2 or 3 days because I took more time on learning said technology. I was not late in the end but I could have finished earlier and start another project.

Comment: @Pete sure, it could look like that, I wouldn't care, if someone was deliberately lying about me, I'll make sure they can't do it again and couldn't care less how they want to take it.

Comment: @Pete I do it slightly differently: "Hello ABC, As we discussed this morning, I will start working on XYZ from (date). Let me know if I have missed something." Now it doesn't look so strange.

Comment: +1 I usually give people the benefit of the doubt and initially, don't worry about getting things in writing (CYA), but once they burn you, document everything. I would have no problem emailing this person and always asking for confirmation to avoid another misunderstanding.

Comment: @pete "(...) because you might lie about it **again** (...)"

Answer (score 11):

Since time has now passed since that conversation, it's increasingly difficult to "solve" this one.

A response would have been "Well, I must have misunderstood you - so what **did** you tell me?".

All you can really do is move forward from here.  Over time, you'll gain more experience in assessing whether what you're being told is appropriate or not.

Comment: What my colleague said was appropriate but misleading and I don't want to be mislead so I don't deliver a project and by that reflecting it bad back to me.

Comment: @wickerman, Personally, I still can't believe that you haven't tried to get to the bottom of the misunderstanding. It's ok if it's your mistake, but how are you to correct your mistake if you still don't know what he truly recommended to you.

Comment: @stephanbranczyk - my mistake is listening and trying to be helpful. From now I'll just wait for them to ask if I can and want, because it seems that being a good person is bad, real bad.

Comment: @wickerman, Getting to the bottom of the misunderstanding was key (even if it meant that it would make you look bad and force you to admit that perhaps you made a mistake). Also, I hope you're just venting and not being serious in your last comment. Reacting in a passive aggressive way is not in your self-interest either. This is not your parents you're dealing with. This your employer. Your employer can get rid of you and replace you anytime they want. Letting your emotions get the better of you is not the way to go about this.

Comment: I was venting, true, sorry. I am trying to make everyone happy, especially the employer so I can continue working there. Cheers and thanks for the advice, I really needed some.